# How to get GCC linker command?

Tags: command-line, gcc, ld

How can I get the command line GCC uses to invoke ld?

I have a problem for an AVR target where GCC apparently adds a linker option which I am trying to override, so I would like to look at the exact options GCC uses for ld.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `gcc -v` to see what commands it runs.  As in,

```
gcc -v -o hello hello.c
```

This will print a lot of output, including the linker command.   The actual output depends on the platform, but the linking command should be near the end.  Alternatively, use

```
gcc -### -o hello hello.c
```

This is like `-v`, but does not actually run any commands and quotes the options.

Another option is

```
gcc -dumpspecs
```

Look for the entry for `link`.

The above command line flags are listed in `gcc --help` and explained on the man page.  Here's [GCC documentation for the spec files](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Spec-Files.html).

Comment: Or use gcc -### which is similar to -v but does not actually execute anything ant quotes all args

Comment: Unfortunately as of GCC 7.3 this further hides the final linker (e.g. `/usr/bin/ld`) behind `collect2`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584243/lets-analyse-collect2-ld-returned-1-exit-status

Comment: What i found by trial and error is that collect2 also accepts the -v flag, so you can take the collect2 invocation from gcc -v, add a -v to it and run it to get the actual ld invocation.

Comment: Does anybody know if we can pass custom arguments to `collect2` from the `g++`/`gcc` frontend invocation command line?