# ld.exe: cannot find -lstrmbase

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am getting a the following error in code blocks using gnu gcc compiler, when I try to compile the code I get these errors:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find-                                          lstrmbase
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 21 seconds)
2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 21 seconds)
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584243/lets-analyse-collect2-ld-returned-1-exit-status

Comment: @herohuyongtao: This is about the linker not finding the libs it was told to link. The code is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 5):

1. First, make sure you have strmbase.lib (or libstrmbase.lib) and z.lib (libz.lib) in your mingw lib directory (it should be "c:/mingw/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/" in your case).
2. Second, if they **do** exist, try to add "c:/mingw/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/" to your library search path.

   There may be GUI option like "LIBRARY PATH" for that, although I don't know about code blocks.

   Alternatively, you can pass an option to gcc "-L c:/mingw/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/" (It must be before "-l..." flags)

EDIT:

1. z.lib is [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/). You can build it using your gcc or download prebuilt binary from MinGW web-site (should be inside MinGW -> Extension).
2. strmbase.lib is from [DirectShow Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can get its source code by installing Windows SDK. There might be someone distributing prebuit binary for MinGW.

Comment: strmbase.lib (or libstrmbase.lib) and z.lib (libz.lib) r not there in my mingw lib. How can i get them

Comment: @lukes [flowfree's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10876053) shows how code::blocks looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Additional note for developers in FreeBASIC under Windows with GTK and C libraries.

For programmers in FreeBASIC it is sufficient to add these definitions to allow the compiler to directly find the directory containing the libraries

```
    #IF DEFINED(__FB_WIN32__)
    #LIBPATH "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib" 
'for windows '
    #ELSE
    #LIBPATH "/usr/lib"
'for linux '
    #ENDIF
```